# Make object follow moving path!

Tags: keyframes, path, interpolation

I need to get an empty to follow a moving path. The path is the guide for a record needle and is a rotating spiral. The empty needs to be still as I will be tracking the needle to it which will simulate it moving slowly toward the centre. I tried simply keyframing it but that doesn't work because it would need to slowly get faster and there a slight wobble in the main vinyl record which I want to keep so the empty needs to move with the path exactly.

I have tried adding a constraint to the empty to follow path and keyframing the offset every (minus) 360 degrees on each next iteration/rotation of the spiral then setting interpolation to linear. This sort of works but there still some movement along the path rather than simply tracking across from the outside to inside which is what I want. If it makes a difference, I'm working in Eevee

Can anyone help with this?[image]

Comment: when you say that you've tried keyframing, you mean you have tried a simple movement on the Y axis? It would be the first thing to try, making sure that the speed of the movement is synchronized with the position of the curve at any moment

Comment: actually the playhead's speed towards the centre of the record is constant, it doesn't get faster (ie: it takes 1/33 of a minute to complete the first rotation as well as the last rotation, during which time the playhead moves by the width of one groove, and all grooves are the same width). For a convincing wobble you could bake the audio to a curve and copy it to the playhead

Comment: I meant that I've set a key frame at the beginning and the end which allows for a smooth transition towards the centre but the wobble means it goes off track which in the end would make the needle look like it's going through the grooves..